# How to find secondary IP addresses from a knife search

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife

I was going through chef, and when this part came where search queries can be put inside the recipe files, I am facing a problem when I try to fetch the secondary IP addresses of a node.
When I try to get the primary IP address, I can get is as

```
>> knife node show web1 -a ipaddress
web1:
  ipaddress: 10.0.2.15
```

But when I try to fetch the secondary IP address, I could see that the key itself is the secondary IP.

```
>> knife node show web1 -a network.interfaces.eth0.addresses
web1:
  network.interfaces.eth0.addresses:
    08:00:27:6E:B1:DB:
      family: lladdr
    192.168.10.43:
      broadcast: 192.168.10.255
      family:    inet
      netmask:   255.255.255.0
      prefixlen: 24
      scope:     Global
    fe80::a00:27ff:fe6e:b1db:
      family:    inet6
      prefixlen: 64
      scope:     Link
      tags:
```

How can I extract the secondary IP field directly in this case, which comes as `192.168.10.43` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`knife search` and `knife node show` display the full object data and are not intended for scripting. We offer `knife exec` for simple Ruby scripts or libraries like `chef-api` or `PyChef` for more complex things.